# How do to get the value of a query with input hidden?

Tags: coldfusion

I have a form which I'm submitting,

```
<cfset cnt=0>
<form method="post" action="add_approver.cfm" name="select_employee">
    <select name="selectDept">
        <option selected>Select  Department</option>
        <cfloop query="department">
           <cfset cnt= cnt+1>  
           <cfoutput>
               <option value="#dept_name#">#csedept_name#</option>
           </cfoutput>
           <input type="hidden"  name="id#cnt#" value="#dept_id#">
        </cfloop>
    </select>

    <p><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit"></p>
</form>
```

When using dump=form. I'm not getting the value of the id. I get:

```
id=#dept_id#,#dept_id#...
```

The other problem is that even thought I'm using `type="hidden"` the dropdown doesn't show
all the options. It is actually showing in text. It is only showing the first item as a list option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put a cfoutput tag around your hidden input tag. Also the hidden input tags are inside of your select tag which is most likely breaking the select tag.

You should loop though the inputs separate from the drop down

Comment: that would give me the id:1,2,3,4,5,6..., not for the one i selected

Comment: so is your intent to get the name and the id of the selected drop down item?

Comment: if you would just like to submit the id of the department put that as the value of the select option. it will come through as #form.selectDept# when you submit the form

Comment: Can you elaborate on why you need the "name", instead of just the id? BTW, there is no need to create a counter variable. Since you are using a query loop, just use `currentRow`. Also, instead of using cfloop plus cfoutput, just switch to a cfoutput loop.

Comment: i didnt need the name , so i change it to getting id , and got it to work